# What does & do at the end of a wc command?

Tags: bash, unix, wc

I am learning the bash environment and cannot understand what I get when running this command:

```
wc filename.txt &
```

It returns an array with a 1-digital integer and another integer, neither of them matches any other result I can get from wc commands (-l, -m, -w, -c). 
Besides the second integer is much bigger than for example the bytes counts. So I terribly wonder.
I browsed forums and found some explanations on the multiple uses of the ampersand in a Unix/Linux environment, but there was nothing that I could relate.
I don't need it, but I won't flush this mystery away, I wish to understand! 
Thanks

Comment: It launches the process in the background, returning the control back to the script immediately. The PID of the new process is stored in `$!`.

Comment: Can you show more context? What makes you think it "returns an array"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I imagine the integers you see are similar to this:

```
[1] 1830
```

`&` launches a command in the background, and the shell prints its job number (`1`) and process id (`1830`). On a longer-running job, you can use those two numbers to control its execution. See the `JOB CONTROL` section of the bash man page for more details.

Comment: Thank you. Now, this is clear, and useful, indeed. @aschepler, you'll find in Kevin's answer the right guess about the way the output was formatted. More exactly, as it appeared: [3] 3230

Answer (score 1):

An ampersand at the end of a WC command tells the shell to start executing the command in the background and to get ready for further command line commands.